# Creating all cases of unordered pairs with elements in a list in python

Tags: python-3.7

I have a list:

```
a_list = ["apple", "pear", "grape", "soil"]
```

I want the elements and the unordered pairs:

```
["apple", "apple pear", "apple grape", "apple soil", "pear", "pear grape", "pear soil", "grape", "grape soil", "soil"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an option using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

a_list = ["apple", "pear", "grape", "soil"]
res = a_list + list(" ".join(comb) for comb in combinations(a_list, 2))
# ['apple', 'pear', 'grape', 'soil', 'apple pear', 'apple grape', 'apple soil',
#  'pear grape', 'pear soil', 'grape soil']
```